# what are the benefits of using keyword FORCE in view creation?

Tags: oracle

I use windows 7 and oracle 11g , so when we create view we use :

```
create force view vw_test as select name from users ;
```

could anyone give me examples when we should use force keyword ??

Answer (score 1):

To quote Oracle's documentation:

> Specify FORCE if you want to create the view regardless of whether the
>   base tables of the view or the referenced object types exist or the
>   owner of the schema containing the view has privileges on them.

So, perhaps, if you needed to create the view in environment where the base tables weren't present then you could, shall we say, FORCE the view to exist even though it would not be usable.  Which would then allow you to write queries against that view since it would exist as an object.  The queries wouldn't run though.  Also,  during a deployment, your views might arrive before your base tables do so you could still FORCE the views into existence until the base tables are created and I believe the views would recompile and become usable the first time they are queried.